# Simplify assign with check for null

Tags: java

**How to simplify the following working code?**

Explanation why it is necessary to have the null-check in case you don't know Apache POI: `row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()` would throw a NullPointerException because `row.getCell(0)` will be `null` if the cell is empty.

```java
String datapoint = (row.getCell(0) != null) ? row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue() : "";
```

I tried this but it isn't working because the NPE will be thrown within the null-check:

```java
String datapoint = Optional.ofNullable(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()).orElse("");
```

Comment: if row.getCell(0) throws an NPE, row is null.

Comment: I see you are using apache poi. Check `getCell(int cellnum, MissingCellPolicy policy)` overloaded method.

Comment: @MiXT4PE yes. Your question also states this: "I tried this but it isn't working because the NPE will be thrown within the null-check:"

Comment: @Stultuske Now I see where the missunderstanding is :) With that "null-check" I was referring to the following `Optional.ofNullable()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Optional.ofNullable(row.getCell(0))
    .map(cell -> cell.getStringCellValue())
    .orElse("");
```

You could use a method reference instead of the lambda, but I wasn't sure which API you were using.

E.g.

```
Optional.ofNullable(row.getCell(0))
    .map(Cell::getStringCellValue)
    .orElse("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Optional#map`

```
Optional.ofNullable(row)
        .map(r -> r.getCell(0))
        .map(cell -> cell.getStringCellValue())
        .orElse("");
```

If you know for sure that `row` is not null, then abstract yourself from the first layer of encapsulation

```
Optional.ofNullable(r.getCell(0))
        .map(cell -> cell.getStringCellValue())
        .orElse("");
```